# Changing UITextView font size after rotation works weird on iOS 5

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextview, frame

I have a UITextView that can be rotated, resized dragged etc, and everything works fine on iOS 6 and iOS 5 when I resize or rotate or drag but when I rotate the UITextView and then resize the following result occurs:

[image]

There are no newlines in that textView right now and it works fine on iOS 6 [image]

For rotation I'm using:

```
- (void)rotation:(CGFloat)newAngle {
    self.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(newAngle *  M_PI / 180);
}
```

And for resize I calculate the new font size for the width user has set and set bounds with:

```
CGSize newFrameSize = [self sizeThatFits:CGSizeMake([[self getLongestStringInTextView] sizeWithFont:self.font].width + 30, CGFLOAT_MAX)];
self.bounds = CGRectMake(self.bounds.origin.x, self.bounds.origin.y, newFrameSize.width, newFrameSize.height);
```

I know its a problem with bounds but I'm not sure what is wrong or if I'm doing anything wrong

Comment: But why are you trying to set bound? Might be there is method like sizeToFit.

Comment: Here, You suppose to use frame instead of bounds

Comment: I'm getting the same result with setting frame and center point and frame also does not work on iOS 6. sizeToFit does the same thing I do and it also does not work with multi line UITextView

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I fixed it.

We have a KVO observer for bounds

```
[self addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"bounds" options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionOld context:NULL];
```

that tracks bounds changes and sets bounds to CGRectZero

```
- (void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath ofObject:(id)object change:(NSDictionary *)change context:(void *)context {
    if ([keyPath isEqualToString:@"bounds"]) {
        [self removeObserver:self forKeyPath:@"bounds"];

        CGRect bounds = self.bounds;
        self.bounds = CGRectZero;
        self.bounds = bounds;

        [self addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"bounds" options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionOld context:NULL];
    }
}
```

which works fine on iOS 6 but does not on iOS 5, which got fixed by also setting frame to CGRectZero

```
- (void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath ofObject:(id)object change:(NSDictionary *)change context:(void *)context {
    if ([keyPath isEqualToString:@"bounds"]) {
        [self removeObserver:self forKeyPath:@"bounds"];

        CGRect bounds = self.bounds;
        CGRect frame = self.frame;
        self.frame = CGRectZero;
        self.bounds = CGRectZero;
        self.frame = frame;
        self.bounds = bounds;

        [self addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"bounds" options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionOld context:NULL];
    }
}
```